# C# - clearing RAM after ReadAllBytes

Tags: c#

I am newbie in C# and recently I tried to make a MD5 hash calculator. But everytime  i check some file, the data remains in RAM until i close the program. In 50kb files or so it doesnt matter, but bigger files may not work. Any clues how can it be disposed or cleared after showing the result ? Thanks

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MD5 md5hash = MD5.Create();
        string inputMD5;
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string fileloc = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            byte[] block = File.ReadAllBytes(fileloc);
            byte[] data = md5hash.ComputeHash(block);
            StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
            }
            inputMD5 = sBuilder.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(inputMD5);
        }
```

Comment: You may want to look at reading the file as a stream rather than all in one go for large files anyway. Then you can use the [`HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(Stream)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.computehash?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Security_Cryptography_HashAlgorithm_ComputeHash_System_IO_Stream_) function.

Comment: Please read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose) topic on MSDN.

Comment: This is not a duplicate for how to call garbage collection manually

Comment: `the data remains in RAM until i close the program` - How did you checked that?

Comment: See the marked duplicates, that should address what it is you are trying to accomplish. It also reinforces why it is always important to include your end goal in your question so thank you for doing that.

Comment: `MD5` is an `IDisposable`-implementing class, so its creation and usage should be wrapped in a `using` construct.